# Make: Parse the tail of a command list as if they were args and not additional rules?

Tags: gnu-make

I remember this schema from [QMK: Quantum Mechanical Keyboard](https://github.com/qmk/qmk_firmware/) where, in order to make the correct keyboard, one wrote something like:

```
make keyboard some_specs::subtype qualifier
```

Which has since been replaced by the `qmk` CLI.

---

In principle, I agree with writing a CLI for a project as important to keyboard hobbyists as QMK.  However, as one person, the `CLI` becomes a huge [Yak Shaving Task](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/15511/yak-shaving) (e.g. [Like This](https://yakshav.es/the-patron-saint-of-yakshaves/)).  And yes, Yak shaving has enormous potential; after all, the html (and javascript) were both yaks ([HTML is a shaved Yak](https://www.thoughtco.com/history-of-html-1991418), [JavaScript -- and later, Rust -- are both Mozilla Yaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brendan_Eich)).

However, when in pursuit of a different sort of objective, I'd like a good stand in for yak shaving w.r.t. meta-project oriented command line interfaces.  My "Go-to" productivity enhancing tool is "GNU-Make" for this particular task.

For example, I have a `jupyter notebook` directory that I'd like to be cross platform compatible (whether on windows, make or various linux systems), self installing, self configuring, and for it to please hide away corporate jargon (aka "jupyter", "notebook", and "lab"), so as to **buffer my precious and limited muscle memory bandwidth from capitalization efforts**.

---

For this reason, I might write -- and have written -- the following make control structure:

```
make install
make run tgt=foo.ipynb pwd=bar [browser=whatever.exe]

# [...] = optional
```

---

My question amounts to: is there a good or `make-ish` way to write:

```
make run foo.ipynb bar whatever.exe
```

Or, as in [QMK](https://github.com/qmk/qmk_firmware/), is there a good way to go about defining a grammar that make was sort of "designed" to handle?

Comment: You can try to put something together by: using `$(MAKECMDGOALS)` to get the list of command-line goals, and `.DEFAULT` to provide a (presumably do-nothing) rule for the "goals" that you really want to treat as just command line arguments.

Comment: `make run=foo.ipynb bar=whatever.exe` would work.

Comment: Maybe you want to try [gmtt](http://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) which has quite some programming constructs to tackle such `make` problems.